# Robocopy "ERROR 123 (0x0000007B) Accessing Source Directory xxx The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Tags: robocopy

I'm using robocopy on a Windows10 computer without any problem.
I copied my bat file to a windows11 computer and can't make it run because of this error:

C:\Users\didie.spyder-py3>robocopy ÔÇ¬"C:\Users\didie.spyder-py3" "C:\Users\didie\ShadowDrive\Sauvegarde-.spyder-py3" /E /S /Z /FFT /NP /NDL /NS /NFL /NC /MT:8

2022/09/05 15:04:15 ERREUR 123 (0x0000007B) Accès au répertoire source C:\Users\didie.spyder-py3\ÔÇ¬C:\Users\didie.spyder-py3
La syntaxe du nom de fichier, de répertoire ou de volume est incorrecte.

i.e. ERROR 123 (0x0000007B) Accessing Destination Directory ...
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

[image]

Here is my one-line bat file:

```
echo "start"
robocopy ‪"C:\Users\didie\.spyder-py3" "C:\Users\didie\ShadowDrive\Sauvegarde-.spyder-py3" /E /S /Z /FFT /NP /NDL /NS /NFL /NC /MT:8
:: robocopy ‪C:"\Users\didie\.spyder-py3" D:"\Sauvegardes\Sauvegarde-.spyder-py3" /E /S /Z /FFT /NP /NDL /NS /NFL /NC /MT:8
pause
```

If anybody knows the trick to make it work...

Comment: I found that the bug only appears on the first line of the file.